# Bazel k8s_deploy Does not Apply Kubernetes Resources to Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bazel, google-cloud-build

I have multiple Bazel rules for deploying Kubernetes

1. [deployments](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/blob/2b47e53c6f8f2b44db09c570fc9873f27b83f9a0/services/ideas/BUILD#L79):

```
load("@k8s_deploy//:defaults.bzl", "k8s_deploy")
k8s_object(
  name = "k8s_deployment",
  kind = "deployment",
  cluster = "cents-ideas",
  template = ":ideas.deployment.yaml",
  images = {
    "gcr.io/cents-ideas/ideas:latest": ":image"
  },
)
```

2. [services](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/blob/2b47e53c6f8f2b44db09c570fc9873f27b83f9a0/services/ideas/BUILD#L88):

```
k8s_object(
  name = "k8s_service",
  kind = "service",
  template = ":ideas.service.yaml",
)
```

And I've put all those `k8s_object` together into a single `k8s_objects` like [this](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/blob/2b47e53c6f8f2b44db09c570fc9873f27b83f9a0/BUILD#L21):

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_k8s//k8s:objects.bzl", "k8s_objects")
k8s_objects(
    name = "k8s",
    objects = [
      ":k8s_deployment",
      ":k8s_service"
    ]
)
```

Lastly, I have a [`cloudbuild.yaml`](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/blob/2b47e53c6f8f2b44db09c570fc9873f27b83f9a0/cloudbuild.yaml) file which runs the `k8s_objects` rule:

```
steps:
  - id: 'push docker images and deploy changes to kubernetes'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
    args: ['run', '//:kubernetes']
```

But the Kubernetes resources are not applied to the cluster, although the Cloud Build succeeds:
[image: cloud build]

[Here](https://00e9e64bac83fdc66c45609b911427a2f5c2d6ad95f35fb827-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/64811142611.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/o/log-5a859279-021b-4b1d-a589-06bce962f6e5.txt?qk=AD5uMEtumX9E_XLDwKbPXDw5MV98lirAnwjMyZgC3cplR0JTjrUOcZwD8kJc8Q5QVuwbVJHLyks3PRMh0uxlHq-TWpkJ5ss25PkEOBAXj5PCtp6amo0Pbxo8KIWyKKlHGec49l_jlHEUGz5Hw8ccWThpFsHzvqjd5JMAStWB60d0eUWHhiAjypyhrnetKHOI1Ibve-PhUuPmcQggp4tRTKmWBb8vjOAdMNaC9Jv-HA0dOXTUqHTaS88iCM56l-51hfzp-aW_ISaltRXrtLQU_gWD6hA9QaC_EGKQ8d9B9BqZoCERO8PwHgWEsM3fF87GTKGWZ2bTiFMVPEiCKBwDhZeX2jtcGeLdM-6aQzKYOAFSUpQ81enMhUJyFxdF-sIpojC4NnyhwDxRPe0MNr0xLWQg9pF0rrKhvBojnAX0fsbxQjTrIaRJS6jBfzwcN5NZJHr6tKK8MXkYvopNfkWaBhkVsvDr5hIr_iKeZ--xgUg9EX98bEPMaOEqRXbIZZDfIopc_qPEi-V1oacadbW5PbjNU_9JbeURqWgUTz6eglHHxcqeTSCXlJxEyanKd4BeKw8QsURzXnfIQlj99Dnq8g7Sye-21PiEVPLEApLMuETbHMBW_uoa3SEbtCNNx3_A0Ix1p5936KliCD57KFzpQkaJGjSI8MDg0eDrJHyVjo-GEdDZKJmVbLnkrez1P_NOJbI73sDWqoytwytx35LN0ypVBtr8KLF_1WQFfmu1F7B4X2sp2m2RGCHReVTvUqys4X76IKAwbWXKBl5-psitqWeAiQLGpZUDKjQGBoj8IwHYZyTNHq2MAAvhY9vByQjSqq1rg7IW5OQGEjftgsj3Oracp1cERLE9xGwHO6X6oM6NfYVJQxDUeRkxeH4f5bFoqMR7mQsaA6Fy) is the full build log.

So basically the images are pushed to the container registry and then the modified `.yaml` files are logged, but **not** applied to my Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to suffix the target with ".create" or ".replace" see [docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#create)

So you would want something like:

```
bazel run //:k8s.create
```

where k8s is your target name.

Comment: I've tried `.create` and `.apply` but both of them result in this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029288

Comment: suggestion 1: do you have kubectl installed in your builder image?  I build a cloud builder image that contains a specific version of bazel + kubectl.

Comment: suggestion 2: in your cloudbuild.yaml you will need to fetch the cluster credentials:
    gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster> --zone <zone>

Comment: would suggestion 2 just be a another step? or how would it look like?

Comment: Something like https://gist.github.com/humphrej/0c68e612229c7341d4125c8f5bf1a15c

Comment: as name i've used `ubuntu` and then bazel is not found: `bash: line 1: bazel: command not found`

Comment: By "name" you mean image name?  Using ubuntu will not work as it needs to have kubectl and bazel installed.  You will need to create your own image using a Dockerfile, combining the best parts of the kubectl and bazel builders: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders

Comment: Ok I might do this if nothing else works... I managed to get it working locally but I still have on issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029288 Would be great if you could check it out