# Cloud Build Bazel Error: "kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so apply cannot be executed"

Tags: kubernetes, bazel, kubectl, google-cloud-build

I am trying to use [rules_k8s](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s) for Bazel to deploy to my Kubernetes cluster.

Thus I have this `cloudbuild.yaml` file, which is executed by Google Cloud Build:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel
    args: ['run', '//:kubernetes.apply']
```

(`//:kubernetes` is just a [`k8s_objects`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#multi-object-actions))

---

On my local machine running `bazel run //:kubernetes.apply` works fine, but
although the Google Cloud Build succeeds, it logs those errors. So the configuration is not applied to my Kubernetes cluster:

```
Target //:kubernetes.apply up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/kubernetes.apply
INFO: Elapsed time: 29.863s, Critical Path: 0.14s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/kubernetes.apply
INFO: Build Event Protocol files produced successfully.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so projection_database_k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so projection_database_k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so event_store_k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so event_store_k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so event_store_k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so event_store_k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so event_store_k8s_deployment.apply cannot be executed.
kubectl toolchain was not properly configured so event_store_k8s_service.apply cannot be executed.
```

I also get a warning from the bazel cache:

```
DEBUG: /builder/home/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/eab0d61a99b6696edb3d2aff87b585e8/external/io_bazel_rules_k8s/toolchains/kubectl/kubectl_toolchain.bzl:28:9: No kubectl tool was found or built, executing run for rules_k8s targets might not work.
```

P.S.: I get the same errors when using `//:kubernetes.create`

## My setup

**Deployments**

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_k8s//k8s:object.bzl", "k8s_object")
k8s_object(
  name = "k8s_deployment",
  kind = "deployment",
  cluster = "gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas",
  template = ":ideas.deployment.yaml",
  images = {
    "gcr.io/cents-ideas/ideas:latest": ":image"
  },
)
```

**Services**

```
k8s_object(
  name = "k8s_service",
  kind = "service",
  cluster = "gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas",
  template = ":ideas.service.yaml",
)
```

**Aggregations**

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_k8s//k8s:objects.bzl", "k8s_objects")
k8s_objects(
    name = "k8s",
    objects = [
      ":k8s_deployment",
      ":k8s_service",
    ]
)
```

**Final composition**

```
k8s_objects(
    name = "kubernetes",
    objects = [
        "//services/ideas:k8s",
        # ...
    ]
)
```

## Update

I've now tried to make my own docker image with Bazel and kubectl:

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel

RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod +x ./kubectl
RUN mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

I pushed it to GCR and changed my `cloudbuild.yaml` to:

```
steps:
  - name: eu.gcr.io/cents-ideas/bazel-kubectl
    args: ["run", "//:kubernetes.apply"]
```

I firstly noticed, that the step took way longer than before. However at the end it throws an error:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig= --cluster=gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas --context= --user= apply -f -
error: cluster "gke_cents-ideas_europe-west3-a_cents-ideas" does not exist
```

[Here](https://00e9e64bac389a379917c629a22bd56b248c258ede42cf265c-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/64811142611.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/o/log-bb2f4b6f-84c2-4f56-af89-15a305e536e0.txt?qk=AD5uMEu_YRlHAfSU5xwyiKmKh8lsG_Gb6O2Q114junmxLrr_VyNhbo_udKtW0yniyjEeWqRQDe-o2NohuW6dXWXmXvyvInr7nimY35qmp-KsvBdWmbCPs-eAcqz6TTk65lcEz-3CwYr7LgKFx0QCOHvZQEzMC6cDquYJNOV6oTGurHmt67gsKkf5DHLiZ7cCdGPsoucsZoByVL6Bf95bfCOch0TByIeQdnkNSVJCn-uoa7JAe3n9ge0TBh01frBLXraYxW_3T9EYsAkNA5vDkdA-UIckqXy86rloR4bruDv_bBwYdqgUkkJ1sl83BDpfT5rbTim11lfeF9a1lbvNPWXB3dO7lfjiiqPIcsDaPpM4V5dRy0InSHO7AYhoJom6chfj-MXLZfcDeuUZdqW2845BGOijkFp0d5vB_YVHp47dMAxI8TYJztiY5ktgQ7n3DzG4aynzLKTXgn6BLGpZqkz70JFW0ZMTE0Gr2afsoIXN1rZeI-BkDyZqs4MXd3m6HfSnO0o9z08IlWgNwzNUf68zTO2gk2BFA1QVvbOFFdfTl9z0wDIMdBRT7vHqgTGXF1bhjK1fWhROAxsJdOQp3qrFftLPFE2POwiFXG-wAqTYULN6usLlAcPLyJcU0VzGmNaDovZdXXzYtcdSzmCgIC6fk-_cOJiq6RsicK_co3sevGqqjL3Hehba-VxyLw930GyuwtzC6zVst3p9-RbKg9xw3tzznikg8q7hIOu9leLfAG7LzmejLkB7dKSrDKUBVDLDtxNzRzK2pNU9D-ErBZcvb2o8qRNWoMrbiZaU0l3cRDRLlrRJYSFt90PbsfHBmyZXcYHSnXyg6rQB08sWq_MM0awUySouQ3IYJZQhNfXFmFUUoAFtafwRC4po1gbzxBzjhtpw6WKj) is the full log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the updated question, now you need to authenticate somehow to GKE inside the container.

First thing, I recommend installing gcloud tool to your container.
Btw, as for the huge container size 1.2 GB, that's because `cloud-builders/bazel` is huge :)

Have a look at our example on slim bazel container version:
https://github.com/aspect-development/bazel-k8s-example/blob/master/tools/Dockerfile.dazel

And here is Dockerfile for installing gcloud and kubectl, so you can grab needed parts from both files:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/gcloud/Dockerfile

The second thing is authenticating, after gcloud is installed it should be easy.
Overall cloudbuild step should look similar to this:

```
- name: <link to your container>
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - -c
  - |
    gcloud container clusters get-credentials cents-ideas --zone europe-west3-a --project cents-ideas
    bazel run //:kubernetes.apply
```

Comment: Sounds good! I will try it. But what would be the `FROM` in my Dockerfile? `debian:9.11-slim` or rather `gcloud-slim`?

Comment: And I will probably don't need all the gcloud components, or do I?

Comment: I think you can use `gcloud-slim`. The result will be just a litter bigger than if using `debian-slim`, but prob more convenient. Dockerfile of `gcloud-slim` is right there in the same repo:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/gcloud/Dockerfile.slim

And yes, you don't need all gcloud components, it's just an example.

Comment: I get an error: `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open gcloud container clusters get-credentials cents-ideas --zone=europe-west3-a --project=cents-ideas
bazel run //:kubernetes.apply` with this Dockerfile: https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/blob/feature/deployment-automation/docker/slim-bazel-kubectl.Dockerfile

Comment: Try the updated version (I forgot -c flag) and let's see how it goes. Actually I didn't check this setup.

Comment: if doesn't work, ping me in bazel slack: https://slack.bazel.build/
@ray

Comment: it seems to work... but with my test running before it the build timed out (10 min+)

Comment: cool. can you run tests in a separate cloudbuild step? and maybe setup the cache to share build artifacts between these steps.

Comment: Tests in a separate step or a separate build? and I am already using a remote cache (but it doesn't seem to make a big difference)

Comment: maybe even in separate build. the cache will help to fasten overall time if you run both tests and deploy in different containers.
also prob you can tune the build timeout.

Answer (score 2):

It complains that it can't find `kubectl` on your machine. If GKE is used, also the `gcloud` sdk needs to be installed.

And also check that authentication is configured for those tools: [kubectl auth](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/), [GKE auth](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials).

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. It works fine on my local machine. But it does not work in the Google Cloud Build :)

Comment: Ahh, right. So, the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel` container doesn't contain `kubectl` tool that's why it doesn't work. You may need to build your own docker image that contains both `kubectl` and `bazel`.

There is also an attempt from rules_k8s authors to have kubectl as a toolchain if it's not found in the environment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/tree/master/toolchains/kubectl#kubectl-toolchain. But when I tried it didn't work for me; not surprising: they state toolchain features as experimental.

Comment: building a custom docker image is something i would like to avoid, which of those three methods didn't work for you? (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/tree/master/toolchains/kubectl#kubectl-toolchain)

Comment: I've now build a custom docker image and it does not find the cluster (see updated question)

Comment: You should add the cluster as shown in this command `kubectl config current-context' which will print the correct cluster that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `kubectl` doesn't come with the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/bazel` docker image. That is why it can't be found.

There are however, efforts to implement the `kubectl` toolchain into Bazel manually: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/tree/master/toolchains/kubectl#kubectl-toolchain. But as those features are currently in experimental status, they often don't work.

More info can be found in this issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/issues/512

> For now, your best bet will be to install kubectl in the container.